# Why in this sentence is not has instead of have?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Hello so I have been practicing some keyword formation and I found this sentence(sentence below in bold), but I wonder why there is "have" and not has when there is 3rd person(HE). Thanks for every answer.

**He might not *have* been informed about his uncle's death.**

Comment: The subject may be 3rd person "he", but the verb "have" is the plain (infinitive) form, not the 1st person "have". The plain form is required because it follows the modal auxiliary verb "might".

Comment: After _might_ and other modal auxiliary verbs, the next verb in the chain has to be an infinitive form (_have_ in this case), and not a tensed form (like _has_). You say _He might not go_ rather than *_He might not goes_

Answer (score 1):

> *He might not have been informed about his uncle's death.*

The subject may be 3rd person "he", but the verb "have" is the plain (infinitive) form, not the 1st person "have", so there is no conflict of tenses.

The plain form is required because it follows the modal auxiliary verb "might", which always requires as its complement a clause headed by a plain-form verb, hence the plain-form "have" not the tensed 3rd person verb "has".

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: To elaborate on this a little, the same would be true if it were "He SHOULD have been informed..." or "He COULD have been informed...". Both of these statements are not definitive. They are not necessarily saying that he WAS informed, but that he would have or could have or should have been informed. The definitive version would be "He WAS informed" (note: I only capitalized the words for emphasis)

Comment: @Brunke Yes, the complement clauses of **all** the modals ("might, must, can. could, should" etc.) are always infinitival (plain form).